# Comments on facebook fan page: "Post comment to my Facebook profile" doesn't work

Tags: facebook, fbml, xfbml, staticfbml

I'd like to add a comment box on my
[facebook fan page](http://www.facebook.com/kakigarden?v=app_4949752878).

So I added on my StaticFBML page:

```
<fb:comments xid="159887744022306">
<fb:title>Leave a comment</fb:title>
</fb:comments>
```

Where "159887744022306" is my page ID. Now it actually posts comments on the page but:

- The feature "Post comment to my Facebook profile" doesn't work. Why?
- How can I control what they share (e.g. adding a picture inside their post) ?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks your question help to solve my issue.but did you solve the issue of post comment to my facebook profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leonardo,

Please sign up and vote for this bug here -> http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=13535

I've had this issue for a while.  I have two identical apps, same code and same settings, just different keys and urls.  On one (old app) "Post comment to my Facebook profile" doesn't work, on the other (new app) everything is perfect.

It doesn't make sense. The more developers vote for this bug, the faster it will be fixed. I hope...

Answer (score 0):

In reference to the Graph API found [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api)

You should use the Feed API

`https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=<auth_token>`  (for your feed) or
`https://graph.facebook.com/<USER ID>/feed?access_token=<auth_token>`

The feed api accepts the following variables (found [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api#publishing))
`message, picture, link, name, caption, description, source`

of which are to be passed via `HTTP POST`

**Also, note** that if you don't pass any parameters to the Feed API call, then it will not set the feed to anything but instead return JSON for yours or another users recent posts.

These api calls can be made via the JavaScript SDK or a PHP SDK. If you are not sure how to set up Graph API to work on your site then I recommend reading, all about the Graph API before trying to implement it as it can be a bit intimidating at first.

Comment: I'm not sure you got me. I'm inside a Facebook fan page, StaticFBML. Not an external website nor an FB app. Is that still valid?

Comment: And if you got me right can you please show me an example for the <fb:comments> code above? thanks.